# Testing after_hook with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I have tag system and field for auto incrementing questions count, that belongs to tag. I am using Mongoid.

Question model:

```
class Question

 has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, after_add: :increment_tag_count, after_remove: :decrement_tag_count
 after_destroy :dec_tags_count
 ...
 private
  def dec_tags_count
    tags.each do |tag|
      tag.dec_questions_count
    end
  end
```

and Tag model:

```
class Tag
  field :questions_count, type: Integer,default: 0
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions

 def inc_questions_count
    inc(questions_count: 1)
  end

  def dec_questions_count
    inc(questions_count: -1)
  end
```

It works fine when I am testing it in browser by hand,it increments and decrements tag.questions_count field when adding or removing tags, but my test for Question model after_destroy hook always fall.

```
   it 'decrement tag count after destroy' do
      q = Question.create(title: 'Some question', body: "Some body", tag_list: 'sea')
      tag = Tag.where(name: 'Sea').first
      tag.questions_count.should == 1
      q.destroy
      tag.questions_count.should == 0
   end

expected: 0
     got: 1 (using ==)
     it {
    #I`ve tried
    expect{ q.destroy }.to change(tag, :questions_count).by(-1)
    }
   #questions_count should have been changed by -1, but was changed by 0
```

need help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `tag` is still referencing the original `Tag.where(name: 'Sea').first`.  I believe you can use `tag.reload` after destroying the question (couldn't try this to confirm) like follows:

```
it 'decrement tag count after destroy' do
  ...
  q.destroy
  tag.reload
  tag.questions_count.should == 0
end
```

But better than this is to update your `tag` to point to `q.tags.first`, which, I believe is what you want:

```
it 'decrement tag count after destroy' do
  q = Question.create(title: 'Some question', body: "Some body", tag_list: 'sea')
  tag = q.tags.first # This is going to be 'sea' tag.
  tag.questions_count.should == 1
  q.destroy
  tag.questions_count.should == 0
end
```